# Search and replace leading apostrophe in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I search and replace the apostrophe (') character in Excel, when it is the first character in a cell?

Specifically, I'd like to be able to search and replace the `=` sign in a formula with `'@` and then later revert it back to `=` and resurrect the original formula.

Comment: Replace the `=` with `#`, then revert back.

Comment: Thanks Jon. That is a much simpler solution to my particular need, though  obviously not the answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a pair of macros to give you the desired functionality:

```
Sub RemoveFormulas()
   For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
      r.Value = Replace(r.Formula, "=", "'@")
   Next r
End Sub

Sub RestoreFormulas()
   Dim r As Range
   For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
      If r.PrefixCharacter = "'" Then
         r.Formula = Replace(r.Value, "'@", "=")
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer.  I haven't tried it yet, as in not at my computer, but it looks like it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Very oddly enough you've chosen a character that is used in Excel to "escape" cells. However I've poked around a bit and was able to find a work around, depending on the size of your file.

If you export your table to a "Text (Tab delimited)" file and then re-import it after modifying the = sign to '@ it should re-import the characters as an actual single quote rather than the escape character. Then you should be able to run a search and replace for '@ to =.

Again this will probably only work as long as you're not doing a huge Excel file, especially without charts and graphs, etc.